# How do i sort a Javascript Object OR Array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, javascript-objects

Okay so i am trying to sort through some results i hold in either a Javascript Object or Javascript Array of Objects, but i cant seem be able to crack this one, however i would like to be able to sort by the different key's values..

What i tried (With the key "amount")

(Imagine the sortable variable holds either the Javascript Object or Javascript Array of Objects)

```
var sortable;
            sortable.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.amount > b.amount;
            });
console.log(sortable);
```

Javascript Object

```
"1": {
    "BTC": {
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "amount": "5.0000000000",
      "rank": "1",
      "usd_coin": "3580.68",
      "btc_coin": "1.00",
      "volume": "1324380000.00",
      "marketcap": "59337865239.00",
      "1h": "1.62",
      "24h": "0.65",
      "7d": "-12.23"
    },
    "ETH": {
      "name": "Ethereum",
      "symbol": "ETH",
      "amount": "1153.0000000000",
      "rank": "2",
      "usd_coin": "247.05",
      "btc_coin": "0.07",
      "volume": "421132000.00",
      "marketcap": "23388713395.00",
      "1h": "2.06",
      "24h": "1.70",
      "7d": "-12.80"
    },
    "LTC": {
      "name": "Litecoin",
      "symbol": "LTC",
      "amount": "15.0000000000",
      "rank": "5",
      "usd_coin": "48.84",
      "btc_coin": "0.01",
      "volume": "276411000.00",
      "marketcap": "2587009816.00",
      "1h": "2.90",
      "24h": "1.84",
      "7d": "-20.80"
    }
  }
```

Array of Objects

```
[
  [
    {
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "amount": "5.0000000000",
      "rank": "1",
      "usd_coin": "3580.68",
      "btc_coin": "1.00",
      "volume": "1324380000.00",
      "marketcap": "59337865239.00",
      "1h": "1.62",
      "24h": "0.65",
      "7d": "-12.23"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Ethereum",
      "symbol": "ETH",
      "amount": "1153.0000000000",
      "rank": "2",
      "usd_coin": "247.05",
      "btc_coin": "0.07",
      "volume": "421132000.00",
      "marketcap": "23388713395.00",
      "1h": "2.06",
      "24h": "1.70",
      "7d": "-12.80"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Litecoin",
      "symbol": "LTC",
      "amount": "15.0000000000",
      "rank": "5",
      "usd_coin": "48.84",
      "btc_coin": "0.01",
      "volume": "276411000.00",
      "marketcap": "2587009816.00",
      "1h": "2.90",
      "24h": "1.84",
      "7d": "-20.80"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Plain JS objects are not sortable.

Comment: I think I'm getting a grasp of your question, but perhaps could you be more specific? Are you returning a sorted version of your object? If so, are you sorting the properties based on their respective values? Or are you sorting the properties alpha-numerically?

An example I/O would go a long way.

Comment: Your code would work if you had an array of objects. You do however have an array of single-element arrays with an object.

Comment: Yes i am trying to return a sorted array, i will look into the problem of "single-element arrays with an object"

Comment: And yes sorry the sort was perfectly fine, i just added a single element array before the objects, which resulted in a bad outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sorting arrays, see the examples on [MDN: Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). The sort function allows you to pass your own custom sorting function to it.

Can also use the map function.